# How do momentum and kinetic energy contribute to total energy of motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum

If considering a straight line trajectory, in what sense are momentum and kinetic energy part of the total energy of motion of an object?

Are there situations when they can be added together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to this question is

$E^2=m^2 c^4+p^2 c^2$

In this equation, which is the relativistic dispersion relation for a single body of mass $ m $, the energy of the body is directly related to its momentum.

Think of it this way, when a body has no momentum, then its energy is

$E=mc^2$

So, mass is a form of energy (with a correction constant of $c^2$). When the body is mass-less, then its energy is

$E=pc$

So, momentum is a form of energy (with a correction constant of $c$).

The kinetic energy of a moving body is a direct manifestation of both the mass of that moving body and its momentum.

So never will you need to add kinetic energy and momentum because, technically speaking, the two are almost exactly the same thing.

Notice that, in Newtonian Mechanics, this kind of statement is hard to make because energy and momentum are related by

$E=\dfrac{p^2}{2m}$.

This equation forbids a body from being mass-less.

Newtonian mechanics also fails to understand mass as a form of energy.

Answer (score 2):

Momentum has units of $\textrm{kg} \phantom{0} \textrm{m} \phantom{0} \textrm{s}^{-1}$, kinetic energy has units of $\textrm{kg} \phantom{0} \textrm{m}^2 \phantom{0} \textrm{s}^{-2}$. Therefore, you can never add them due to them being different things - like apples and bananas.

For an object in the frame of classical mechanics, $E_{\textrm{kin}}=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ with $p$ its impulse and $m$ its mass are the kinetic energy which together with the potential energy of the object define its energy.